# Proving $F(x)=\int_x^{2x}\frac{1}{t^4+1}dt$ is an odd function$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> Prove the following:
>
> $1.)  F(x)=\int_x^{2x}\frac{1}{t^4+1}dt$ is an odd function $\left[F(-x)=-F(x)\right]$
>
> 2.) Find the intervals where F is decreasing and where F is increasing
>
> 3.) Use the squeeze theorem to prove $\lim_{x \to \infty} F(x)$ and find it's value

1.) Ok so I'm stuck on the first one.

I had an idea that goes like this:

$$F(-x)=F(-x)+F(x)-F(x)$$

$$F(-x)=\int_{-x}^{-2x}\frac{1}{t^4+1}dt +\int_x^{2x}\frac{1}{t^4+1}dt-\int_x^{2x}\frac{1}{t^4+1}dt$$

$$F(-x)=-F(x)+\int_{-x}^{-2x}\frac{1}{t^4+1}dt+\int_x^{2x}\frac{1}{t^4+1}dt$$

Is there anyway to continue with this idea or did I reach a dead end? It seems as though none of the definite integral properties can help me prove that the two integrals on the right are somehow 0.

Would a substitution be better suited to prove this?

Comment: Yes, think about $t=-u$

Comment: if $f'(x)$ is even and $f(0) = 0$ then $f(x)$ is odd. here $f'(x) = \frac{1}{x^4+1}$ is even, so $f(x) = \int_0^x f'(t) dt$ is odd, hence $F(x) = f(2x)-f(x)$ is odd too

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use the substitution $t = -u$ so that the limits change from $x \mapsto -x$ and $2x \mapsto -x$ giving $$F(x) = \int_{-x}^{-2x} \frac{-1}{(-u)^4 + 1} \, \mathrm{d}u = -F(-x)$$ since $\mathrm{d}u = -\mathrm{d}t$ and $(-u)^4 = u^4$. Keep in mind that $t$ and $u$ are dummy variables.

Answer (score 1):

$$F(-x)=\int_{-x}^{-2x}\frac{1}{t^4+1}dt$$
$$=-\int_{-2x}^{-x}\frac{1}{t^4+1}dt$$
Now, because the integrand is even, it equals
$$=-\int_{x}^{2x}\frac{1}{t^4+1}dt$$
$$=-F(x)$$

Answer (score 1):

Just substitute $u=-t$. i.e. $\int^{-2x}_{-x} \frac{1}{t^4 +1}dt=\int^{2x}_{x} \frac{1}{(-u)^4 +1}(-du)=-\int^{2x}_{x} \frac{1}{u^4 +1}du$

EDIT:

Also in case you need a hint for 3) note that for $t>0$, $\frac{1}{(t+1)^4}<\frac{1}{t^4 +1}<\frac{1}{t^4}$. You can easily integrate these lower and upper bounds and you will find that their limits are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Use the change of variable $t=ux$. Then

$$F(x)=\int_x^{2x}\frac{dt}{t^4+1}=x\int_1^2\frac{u\,du}{x^4u^4+1}.$$

Now it should be obvious that $F(-x)=-F(x)$.